# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError after approximately one day celery running

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, redis-py

This is my full trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 283, in trace_task
    uuid, retval, SUCCESS, request=task_request,
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 256, in store_result
    request=request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 490, in _store_result
    self.set(self.get_key_for_task(task_id), self.encode(meta))
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 160, in set
    return self.ensure(self._set, (key, value), **retry_policy)
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 149, in ensure
    **retry_policy
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 243, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 169, in _set
    pipe.execute()
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2593, in execute
    return execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error)
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2447, in _execute_transaction
    connection.send_packed_command(all_cmds)
  File "/home/server/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 532, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/home/pserver/backend/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 436, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 0 connecting to localhost:6379. Error.
[2016-09-21 10:47:18,814: WARNING/Worker-747] Data collector is not contactable. This can be because of a network issue or because of the data collector being restarted. In the event that contact cannot be made after a period of time then please report this problem to New Relic support for further investigation. The error raised was ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BlockingIOError(11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable')),).
```

I really searched for ConnectionError but there was no matching problem with mine.

My platform is ubuntu 14.04. This is a part of my redis config. (I can share if you need the whole redis.conf file. By the way all parameters are closed on LIMITS section.)

```
# By default Redis listens for connections from all the network interfaces
# available on the server. It is possible to listen to just one or multiple
# interfaces using the "bind" configuration directive, followed by one or
# more IP addresses.
#
# Examples:
#
# bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
bind 127.0.0.1

# Specify the path for the unix socket that will be used to listen for
# incoming connections. There is no default, so Redis will not listen
# on a unix socket when not specified.
#
# unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
# unixsocketperm 755

# Close the connection after a client is idle for N seconds (0 to disable)
timeout 0

# TCP keepalive.
#
# If non-zero, use SO_KEEPALIVE to send TCP ACKs to clients in absence
# of communication. This is useful for two reasons:
#
# 1) Detect dead peers.
# 2) Take the connection alive from the point of view of network
#    equipment in the middle.
#
# On Linux, the specified value (in seconds) is the period used to send ACKs.
# Note that to close the connection the double of the time is needed.
# On other kernels the period depends on the kernel configuration.
#
# A reasonable value for this option is 60 seconds.
tcp-keepalive 60
```

This is my mini redis wrapper:

```py
import redis

from django.conf import settings


REDIS_POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host=settings.REDIS_HOST, port=settings.REDIS_PORT)


def get_redis_server():
    return redis.Redis(connection_pool=REDIS_POOL)
```

And this is how i use it:

```py
from redis_wrapper import get_redis_server

# view and task are working in different, indipendent processes

def sample_view(request):
    rs = get_redis_server()
    # some get-set stuff with redis



@shared_task
def sample_celery_task():
    rs = get_redis_server()
    # some get-set stuff with redis
```

Package versions:

```
celery==3.1.18
django-celery==3.1.16
kombu==3.0.26
redis==2.10.3
```

So the problem is that; this connection error occurs after some time of starting celery workers. And after first seem of that error, all the tasks  ends with this error until i restart all of my celery workers. (Interestingly, celery flower also fails during that problematic period)

I suspect of my redis connection pool usage method, or redis configuration or less probably network issues. Any ideas about the reason? What am i doing wrong?

(PS: I will add redis-cli info results when i will see this error today)

**UPDATE:**

I temporarily solved this problem by adding [--maxtasksperchild](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting) parameter to my worker starter command. I set it to 200. Ofcourse it is not the proper way to solve this problem, it is just a symptomatic cure. It basically refreshes the worker instance periodically (closes old process and creates new one when old one reached 200 task) and refreshes my global redis pool and connections. **So i think i should focus on global redis connection pool usage way and i'm still waiting for new ideas and comments.**

Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Have you enabled the rdb background save method in redis ??
if so check for the size of the `dump.rdb` file in `/var/lib/redis`.
Sometimes the file grows in size and fill the `root` directory and the redis instance cannot save to that file anymore.

You can stop the background save process by issuing 
`config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no`
command on `redis-cli`

Comment: Thanks. I just checked it and it is 589MB. But it is the file which redis uses it for persistence purposes, right? I mean, if i disable it, i will lose my queues after a reboot of the machine, won't i? I am also checking disk size a few times in a day. And lastly, could it reduce dump file size if i restart the workers? I mean, I guess, the symptoms aren't matching.

Comment: The command provided is not to  stop background save, but to prevent redis from stopping in case of errors regarding background save method .

Comment: I got it. But we must consider that i can reach redis data via redis-cli on that error times. So redis is not stopping completely, only blocks my celery clients.